# Null Pointer Exception Error on a Constructor

Tags: java, eclipse, loops, null, nested

So I have a constructor here that copies PandemicModel other to another grid called this.grid. I have an error saying java.lang.NullPointerException and another error that when I click the error on Eclipse it highlights my last statement on the nested for loop. I don't know how to fix the problem. Any ideas?

```
/**
 * Copy constructor
 * It is assumed that other is not null and that this PandemicModel 
 * is a deep copy of other (i.e., other.grid is copied into a new
 * 2-dim array this.grid)
 * @param other the PandemicModel that is copied
 */
public PandemicModel (PandemicModel other){

    this.rows = other.rows;
    this.columns = other.columns;

    for (int i=0; i<other.rows; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<other.columns; j++){
            this.grid[i][j] = other.grid[i][j];
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is `grid`? Has it been initialized? On either `this` or `other`?

Comment: A stack trace (and the declarations of those fields) would be invaluable here.

Comment: grid, this, and other have all been declared and initialized inside an Abstract class. This method is just part of a class that has inherited all the fields and methods that my abstract class has.

Comment: Most likely need `this.grid = new (Type)[rows][columns];`

Comment: Java Devil, Im not sure what you mean or where to put that...

Comment: It never ceases to amaze me that people can't read java exceptions! Even with no further info you can print this.grid and other and other.grid and find out which one is null!

Comment: (Type) in my above comment is what ever type of array `grid` is and you most likely have not initialised it correctly. Without more code we cannot say for sure. This would be required in the constructor you have shown.

Comment: @user3321427 Are you *sure* `this.grid` was initialized in the abstract class?  Note that since you don't have a `super` call in the constructor, it will automatically call `super()` with no arguments.  Maybe you need to post the code for the no-argument constructor of the parent class.

Comment: yes, I am sure. Our professor has provided everything in an abstract class and also a testProgram. All I have to do is write the methods themselves.

Comment: The thing on the exact line the stack trace you haven't posted is telling you is `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think as @Java Devil was implying, you are not initializing your grid object.

your code probably needs to look like this:

```
public PandemicModel (PandemicModel other){

    this.rows = other.rows;
    this.columns = other.columns;

    this.grid = new (Type)[this.rows][this.columns];

    for (int i=0; i<other.rows; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<other.columns; j++){
            this.grid[i][j] = other.grid[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Where `Type` is replaced with the datatype for grid.